# SQL Performance while comparing strings

Tags: sql, string, select

I have 2 fields varchar in the database. One with size 50 and the other with size 2.
I have to make a select comparing with the 2 fields. I want to know if it is more performance to compare first by the short field and then by the other field. Or is exactly the same?

Comment: What type of comparison are you doing?

Comment: also, is any of the fields in an index?

Comment: the work is the same, the engine will likely optimize the query to the shortest method.  Try both and find out is the only real answer as it depends on database statistics, indexes, and the RDBMS.

Comment: i am doing an = comparison. And the fields aren't index.

Comment: If the fields are not indexed the query is not likely to be performant.

Comment: If the fields aren't indexed, then the amount of time comparing the two columns is going to be dwarfed by the amount of time spent fetching data from disk to compare.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no difference whatsoever *and* you have basically no control over it.  When you say:

```
where col1 = 'A' and col2 = 'ABC'
```

The SQL engine is free to do the comparison in any order it likes.  In fact, it might do one comparison by looking up values in an index and another comparison on the resulting values in the columns.  So, what looks very similar in a query may have very, very different execution plans.

Also, in general, operations on rows are a small amount of effort compared to reading in the data in the first place.  Your time is being wasted on such micro-optimizations.  If you want your code to run faster, you need to think about the whole picture.

Comment: You do have **some** control... just not much.  [ms SQL Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187713.aspx) or [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements006.htm#i35922) are one form of control.  Database statistics would be another.

Comment: @xQbert . . . You are right, I shouldn't have written "no control" since there is some control in some databases.  However, even Oracle's `Ordered_Predicates` hint doesn't work with indexes, and I'm not aware of an equivalent in SQL Server.

Comment: It sounded nit-picky and I didn't like writing it but I didn't want a future reader thinking there was no chance. (I'd happily delete the comments if you want to change the answer!) :D